# Matrix generalization of dot product

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I want a flexible function that computes a dot product between two vectors of length n, but to take advantage of vectorization in numpy, I want to do that on m such pairs. So, I want to take two n x m matrices and get 1 x m matrix where each value is the result of pair-wise inner-products between columns.

How would one do that organically using Numpy?

Comment: Have you looked at `numpy.matmul`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: All variants of matmul and dot failed me, as well as basic functionalities of tensordot. 
Matmul is seemingly not the solution, as matrix multiplication of two n x m cannot yield 1 x m in any way I am aware of.

Comment: `matmul` can be made to work - just move the `m` dimension to the front, `(a.T[:,None,:]@b.T[:,:,None]).squeeze()`.  Without the `squeeze` the result is `(m,1,1)`.

Comment: Would you mind putting this as an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
a = np.random.rand(3, 5)
b = np.random.rand(3, 5)

np.einsum('nm,nm->m', a, b)

array([0.86657218, 1.15263707, 0.49402075, 1.06340726, 0.92129474])
```

Read `'nm,nm->m'` as take two `nxm` arrays, multiply them element-wise and sum along dimension of length `m`.  Or basically what you asked.

You can generalize this with more arrays and summing along any dimension

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
a = np.random.rand(3, 5, 10)
b = np.random.rand(3, 5, 10)
c = np.random.rand(3, 5, 10)

np.einsum('lnm,lnm,lnm->l', a, b, c)

array([5.48255315, 5.74368772, 4.21100655])
```

And also what @wim answered!

Comment: 'n...,n...' will work on 1d, 2d, 3d etc, always summing on the 1st dim.  As general as @wim's

Answer (score 2):

Normal array multiplication is element-wise.  So, what you want seems to be:

```
(a1*a2).sum(axis=0)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a1
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> a2
array([[5, 4, 3],
       [2, 1, 0]])
>>> (a1*a2).sum(axis=0)
array([6, 8, 6])
```

I'm not sure how to make it more "organically", sprinkle on some tarragon maybe?

Comment: Although this is correct, I was hoping for a multidimensional generalization with a single function, if such a thing exists.